# SP07 - Export to word, problem with Response-encoding

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, export, word

I have a button-event where exports data from SharePoint(unicode format) to Word(unicode format). The problem is with encoding.

**this is my code:**

```
string filename = String.Format("Results_{0}_{1}.doc", DateTime.Today.Month.ToString(), DateTime.Today.Year.ToString());

                //Creating HttpContext                                           
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";

                //File name for the exported word document
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + filename);

                //Giving heading to the Word Document with style
                StringBuilder strHTMLContent = new StringBuilder();
                strHTMLContent.Append(" <h1 title='Heading' align='Center' style='font-family:verdana;font-size:80%;color:black'><u>  </u></h1>".ToString());
                strHTMLContent.Append("<br>".ToString());
                strHTMLContent.Append("<table style=margin-top: 8px; border=1 bordercolor=#808080 frame=hsides rules=rows cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100%>".ToString());
                //Looping through each list item in  the list


                strHTMLContent.Append("<tr><td><strong>Drujestvo</strong>"  + ddCompany.SelectedItem.Text + "</td></tr>");
                strHTMLContent.Append("<tr><td>" + ddProject.SelectedItem.Text + "</td></tr>");
                //foreach (SPListItem oListItem in collListItems)
                //{

                //    strHTMLContent.Append("<tr><td>" +  oListItem["Choice_Field_Name"].ToString() + "</td></tr>");

                //}
                strHTMLContent.Append("</table>".ToString());
                strHTMLContent.Append("<br><br>".ToString());
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strHTMLContent);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
```

**This is my Result:**
[image]

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;

**This solve my problem :)**